# WCF Service Accounts

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have a WCF self-hosted as a Windows Service.

When I start the service (under the NETWORK_SERVICE account), I can consume the service from my ASP.NET application on a different server.

However, the business rules have changed. Now I need to run the service under my own account. I am able to stop the service, and start it again under my account. No problem there.

Until I try to consume the service from my ASP.NET application on the other service. I get:

```
A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception
```

I'm relatively certain there's something I need to do security wise to eliminate this error, being new to all this I just don't know what.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this is a sign of a missing or [misconfigured SPN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/90ab4603-804a-43a1-a703-c0fb6a12ee41), which gets in the way when you're using windows authentication (at the transport or message level) and Kerberos is being negotiated.

Notice that how/when the error manifests itself might depend on the way the hostname (or IP address) of the service host is used in the URL used by the client, since WCF will try, by default, to deduce the right SPN to use based on the URL information, unless you explicitly override it by setting the endpoint identity.

So likely all you need to do is register an SPN (using setspn.exe) for your new service and make sure your client uses an appropriate identity.

There's some more extra information on how WCF uses service identities [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733130.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628618.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650619.aspx#AdditionalConsiderations).

Comment: It's not that the error manifests itself by hostname/ip, it's noticing how the error manifests by the ACCOUNT the service is run under. The service will execute when run under the network_service account, but I can't call it when it runs under my account (which is what I need it to do).

Comment: in other words, if I run the service under 'network_service' credentials, I don't get the 'SSPI failed' error. But when I run the service under my credentials, I get the error.

Comment: I know that; I was just outlining a different scenario in which the same error can pop up. The SPN depends on the account the service is running under, since that can be relevant. NETWORK SERVICE usually has a working SPN by default, so you don't need to mess with it. Domain accounts don't get the same behavior.

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to see what you're saying. Unfortunately though, neither server has the setspn.exe utility (searched both C:\ drives). Any other way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Setspn.exe is never installed by default. You need to grab it from the windows server support tools package (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773257(WS.10).aspx).

Comment: Also, here's the info for 2008: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731241(WS.10).aspx and I also believe you'll find it on system32 in win7 installations.

Comment: Thanks, but just one more question -- Do I run setspn.exe on the 'server/provider' WCF or the 'client/consumer' ASP application?

Comment: AFAIK, SetSPN registers stuff in Active Directory, not on the machine itself, so it shouldn't matter where you run it, I think. But yeah, normally, you'll be adding an SPN for the server/provider, not the client/consumer.